# Sum including all numbers ONLY want to sum currency valued

Tags: sum, google-sheets-formula, currency

I have a cell with a bunch of numbers, Ing currency dollar values I only want to sum the dollar values

Tons of suggested formulas and watched videos with no luck

Cell includes:  3d youth barrels $5, 4d open barrels $5, 3d poles $5
ONLY sun $5 values do not include 3 (from 3d) nor 4 (from 4d)!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Looks like you want to choose only numbers that are preceded by a dollar sign.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

If the values are all in one cell, and separated by commas, you can split by commas and use REGEXEXTRACT to get the values preceded by $:

```
=SUM(INDEX(1*REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1,","),"\$(\d+)")))
```